# Cookie popup at bottom of the page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am an newbie in jQuery & CSS. I need to show a pop-up which is similar to below url.

When we visit first time in the below url, there is pop-up coming up at the bottom of the page.

I could copy the pop-up div content using developers tool option, also I could copy entire CSS file but I'm not able to copy that particular element's CSS style.

Is there any possible way to copy that particular element's CSS style or any reference CSS which can create a pop-up with similar style.

www2.chubb.com/uk-en/brexit/

Comment: Use Google to fix your 'problem'. Here is a simple site, found in Google. https://cookieconsent.insites.com/

Comment: We are not a code writing service.

Comment: @james Douglas - I know that

Comment: @Dennis - Thanks for sharing the reference link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have tried copying the CSS code of the element yet, but if you did I think it should simply work as the element just need to have the background color using `rgba(0,0,0,.8)` for the `background` attribute.

The  position, you can use position absolute or fixed (it's depend).

```css
.pop-up {
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.background {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2XX5zDThC3U/maxresdefault.jpg') 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="pop-up">
    <p>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
      laborum." Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC </p>
  </div>
</div>
```